# Stored procedure that takes multiple inparameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm in the making of a stored procedure that can take multiple parameters in. For example if a X is null then it can take Y if you dont have Y value you can take Z. That is the point so far, then it has to make a check in the table if a value exists if the value in the column in the table does not exist it should place default value. So far this is my coding, I'm open for suggestions how to move on..

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Support_status_Check_](@ANr int, 
@gnr int =  0,@idnr varchar(20) = null,@DefaultAction varchar(20) 
= 'DEFAULT_Status')
as

--declare @user as varchar(30)
declare @atnr as integer

if @gnr = 0 and @idnr is null
select @gnr = Gnr from dbo.tableA where Anr = @Anr

if @Anr is null and @idnr is null 
select @Anr = Anr from dbo.TableA where GNr = @gnr
```

Comment: Use the T-SQL Coalesce expression for the null checking, to return the first non-null value. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: Just a general observation: meaningful parameter/variable names make SQL much easier to read. `DefaultAction` is good; `gnr` and `ANr`, not so much.

Comment: Yes Sorry about that, those variables are namned that in the system that's why I used their original name..

Answer (score 0):

as for your part "if a X is null then it can take Y if you dont have Y value you can take Z"
you can do it like

```
 select  isnull(X,isnull(Y,Z))
```

here if X is null it will solve the expression after "," .. so it will solve isnull(Y,Z) and if Y is null ,it will take Z as a solution.

So you can apply this idea in your code

check this for more about isnull function http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx